# Watson explorer advanced edition

Tags: ibm-watson

Is it possible to change the way that WEX process a word in the "**Linguistic Analysis Annotator**" section of the pipeline? In my case I have a word, in spanish, that I need as a noun, not as an adjective.

[image: Neutral sentiment]

"**Seguro**" is taken as an adjective, but as a positive sentiment. Also I defined "**muy lento**" as negative expression in the "**Sentiment Analysis**" section in WEX. Final result is a neutral phrase.

Is it possible to change the way that "**Linguistic Analysis Annotator**" handles the "**Seguro**" word?

Comment: Please post text rather than a picture of text.

Comment: Although I never tried personally, but I know there is a way to specify your own version of the built in LEX and OOV dictionaries